# Помогите внедрить рекламу в приложение

Tags: java, android

По инструкции не могу выходит много ошибок и рекламу не выводит в fragment_home.xml

там код баннера, как мне сделать баннер в этом коде?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;




import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private View root;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: making the layout visible");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


}




@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: view created successfully");
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.category_list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
    mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    root = view.findViewById(R.id.home_root);
    //setting adapter
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(),root, StaticUtils.categoryList, StaticUtils.imagesList,0);  //adapter attached
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: gets called.");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    //getting the lists ready
    StaticUtils.categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.featured,"Featured"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.abstruct,"Abstract"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.army,"Army"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.baby,"Baby"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.beach,"Beach"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.cars,"Cars"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.city,"City"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.foods,"Foods"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.girls,"Girls"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.macro,"Macro"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.nature,"Nature"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.religious,"Religious"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.sports,"Sports"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.stars,"Stars"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.technology,"Technology"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.water,"Water"));
    StaticUtils.categoryList.add(new CategoryItem(R.drawable.wildlife,"Wildlife"));
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: clicked item");
    NetworkUtils network = new NetworkUtils(getContext());

    if(network.checkConnection(root)){      //if network connected
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_FRAG_ID,0);
        if (position!=0){
            i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_SEARCH_DATA,StaticUtils.categoryList.get(position).getmTitle());
        }
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

Мой hom_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id_banner1">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_cat_title"
    android:text="@string/collections"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_16sp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/category_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий код:

```
private void loadAdBanner() {
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_BANNER_ID);
    adView.setAdSize(SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adContainer.addView(adView);
        }
    });
    AdRequest.Builder request = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adView.loadAd(request.build());
}
```

В xml добавьте контейнер для баннера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
```

И в манифест ваш APPLICATION_ID

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-nnnnnnnnnnnnnn~nnnnnnnnn" />
```

Comment: ошибка в new AdView(this);

Comment: Туда нужно передавать контекст. Посмотри в логи, что пишет?

Comment: https://ibb.co/C2f93bJ

Comment: Передай туда контекст)
Я не вижу где ты вызываешь код.
Если это фрагмент, то используй getContext()

Comment: @EvgenySermyagin Получилось?

Comment: Нет куча ошибок. Может есть какая нибудь готовая библиотека?

Comment: Ахах)
Готовая либа называется `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads`
А я привел тебе реализацию. Проще некуда.